# How to route requests in codeigniter so we can serve static css, js and img files?

Tags: php, css, codeigniter

I am using codeigniter framework for a project I have, but I have a small issue I can't solve. I want to separate css styling and js scripts from the views, so I have them in separate folders, /css and /js respectively, both are in the assets folder which is in the root folder of my project. The overall structure is like this:

/project-folder

----/application

----/system

----/assets

--------/css

--------/js

----index.php

Now, I have a controller called MyLibrary that has a method called newentry, which when it gets called loads the newentry view.

```
<?php 
class MyLibrary extends CI_Controller
{
    public function newentry()
    {
    //The upload form
    $this->load->view('newentry');
    }
}
```

The newentry view is a simple upload form that uses a style.css and script.js for styling and validation etc... I am using the base_url() method of codeigniter to include the path and file name of the files above.

```
<html>
<head>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="<?php echo base_url();?>assets/css/style.css">
    <title><?php echo $title; ?></title>
</head>

<body>
 <form class = "dropezone" action = 'upload' method = 'POST' enctype = 'multipart/form-data'>
    <input type="file" name="document" />
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

This line is where I have a problem:
    href="assets/css/style.css">

the generated string is the correct path, meaning localhost/project-name/assets/css/styles.css, however, the request gets made to this url:

```
http://localhost/project-name/MyLibrary/localhost/test-pages/assets/css/style.css
```

which is of course, not where the files are. Does anyone know why is this happening?

Also, how to fix this? should I add a route by hand? if so, how to make a controller that serves static files?

Comment: Is `base_url` set in `config.php`?

Comment: Yes, it is set like this: $config['base_url'] = 'localhost/test-pages/';

Comment: Try adding the protocol to base_url like this: ` $config['base_url'] = 'http://localhost/test-pages/';`

Comment: `$config['base_url']` should be assigned by `'http://localhost/test-pages/'`. Protocol scheme is needed too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out why the request wasn't made to the correct url. So no, it's not about adding the protocol scheme. `It has to do with how user agents calculate the base url`. Let me explain:

When we use a link tag in HTML, we specify the href attribute, which is a URI. Now, if it's an absolute path there is no problem really, the resource just get's fetched, however, there is a little problem with relative paths, like the one I use. You see, the user-agent or the browser is *programmed to append that href to a base url* and there's different ways how they calculate that base url, [here's what W3C has to say:](https://www.w3.org/TR/html4/struct/links.html#h-12.4)

> User agents must calculate the base URI for resolving relative URIs
>   according to [RFC1808], section 3. The following describes how
>   [RFC1808] applies specifically to HTML.
>
> User agents must calculate the base URI according to the following
>   precedences (highest priority to lowest):
>
> 1. The base URI is set by the BASE element.
> 2. The base URI is given by meta data discovered during a protocol interaction, such as an HTTP header (see [RFC2616]).
> 3. By default, the base URI is that of the current document. Not all HTML documents have a base URI (e.g., a valid HTML document may appear
>      in an email and may not be designated by a URI). Such HTML documents
>      are considered erroneous if they contain relative URIs and rely on a
>      default base URI.

so, the solution was simple enough after reading this passage, I just had to specify the base url to be used, in the HTML document with the base tag, like this:

```
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Home Page - wellcom</title>
        <base href = "<?php echo base_url(); ?>">
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <h3>HANIX</h3>
    </body>
</html>
```

and it worked like magic.

Anyway, thank you for your replies, I hope this answer will be helpful to others.

Answer (score 0):

Try your stylesheet link this way

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="<?php echo base_url('assets/css/style.css');?>">
```